# display negative x-values in AndroidPlot

Tags: android, androidplot

I want to create a coordinate system like this:

http://xahlee.info/SpecialPlaneCurves_dir/CoordinateSystem_dir/rectangular_coord.png

[image]

I tried creating it with AndroidPlot, but I couldn't figure out how. 
My main problems: I can't figure out how to draw negative x-values and how to keep the x/y-axis permanent on the screen, even when zooming. 
Does someone have an solution for this?

Comment: Have u tried my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
plot.centerOnDomainOrigin(0);
plot.centerOnRangeOrigin(0);
```

where `plot` is `XYPlot` .